# denied access file

Tags: php, .htaccess

how denied access one file from outside?

```
if you go www.mysite.com/file.txt - ban.
if you go /home/public_html/file.txt - ok.
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: Can't you just place it outside the document root?

Comment: `.exe` files never opens in browser

Comment: If you dont want someone to access it from outside, dont put it somewhere, where its accessable from outside ;) You maybe want to describe, why its really impossible to put it somewhere else. @diEcho: But you can download it.

Answer (score 2):

Read this [htaccess tricks](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php)
 or [this one](http://www.htpasswdgenerator.com/apache/htaccess.html)

for specific file

```
<Files file.txt>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
</Files>
```

for all extension (`.txt`)

```
<Files ~ "\.txt$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're using Apache, you can use .htaccess files to restrict certain file types.

```
<FilesMatch "\.txt$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```